# Socket.io and RedisStore - simple example not work (event.js:66)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I try to run this example: http://blog.rstack.cc/post/node_js__using_socket_io_with_cluster_module

With node.js v0.8.8 and latest Socket.io (0.9.10) installed. But I get this errors: http://pastebin.com/VfzhxNZX

with node.js v0.8.11 error is in event.js:68, instead of :66 when node v0.8.8

Anybody knows why this example can't run?

Comment: Have you installed Redis on this machine? Is it listening on the same port as in the error message? The error is basically telling you that your code can't connect to a Redis installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need Redis installed on your machine. You can [download it here.](http://redis.io/download)